# Play audio from a Linux PC to an Android telephone over bluetooth

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth

I want to stream my speakers output from PC to my android phone. I exactly want to call somebody and play him my PC speakers output. How can I do that? I think that tricking my phone that my pc is headset will work, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: See e.g. [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/364715/can-i-use-my-linux-pc-laptop-as-a-bluetooth-headset-for-my-mobile-phone). If HFP doesn't work anymore, what I'd try next is to mimic the HFP setup in Pulseaudio.

Comment: HFP is dead, you can't compile it on newer (>12.01) versions. I tried HFP in Pulseaudio but it wouldn't change it's mode -  I will try again in free time.